# SQL Server - how to use null and value together in CASE THEN statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have problem when using a `CASE WHEN` statement because where column is value string have to use equal sign  like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE (field = (CASE WHEN @PaidStatus = 1 THEN 'HELLO' ELSE NULL END)
```

but the null value cannot be compared with the equal operator (I need to write `WHERE field IS NULL`  not `WHERE field = NULL`).

So how could I do this?

Comment: tip: `case expressions` evaluate to a single value and are not as large in concept as a `statement`, such as a `select statement` or an `update statement`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this do the trick?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE (field = 'HELLO' AND @PaidStatus = 1)
   OR (field IS NULL AND @PaidStatus <> 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To return only rows where field = parameter value, OR, all rows if the parameter is NULL, then:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE (field = @PaidStatus OR @PaidStatus IS NULL)
```

for other combinations, such as parameter value is 1 then field equals 'HELLO', or, all rows if parameter is null:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE ((field = 'HELLO' AND @PaidStatus = 1) OR @PaidStatus IS NULL)
```

be careful with parentheses, you may find indenting makes it far easier to understand, e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE (
         (field = 'HELLO' AND @PaidStatus = 1) 
      OR (field = 'GOODBYE' AND @PaidStatus = 2) 
      OR @PaidStatus IS NULL
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the syntax with the case work?
A `CASE` returns a value and can have multiple `WHEN`.
So you can compare against the returned value.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE 
(CASE 
 WHEN @PaidStatus = 1 AND field = 'HELLO' THEN 1
 WHEN field IS NULL THEN 2
 ELSE 0
 END) > 0
```

Which can be handy if you got many different criteria to put in the `CASE`.
But if it's only 2 then just using `OR` will be shorter.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE (field IS NULL OR (@PaidStatus = 1 AND field = 'HELLO'));
```